# symfony/validator composer package not loading correctly

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm using the symfony/validator as project dependencies. But I can't get the validator classes in the vendor/autoload.php. When I looked in the vendor/symfony/validator folder I got the dir structure above:

```
vendor
- symfony
-- validator
--- Symfony
---- Component
----- Validator
------ composer.json
------ ValidatorBuilder.php
```

**update**: *I found this directory differs from the others depedencies in the vendor dir. I checked it on github repository of symfony/validator and there's no structure like this one*

And the code below doesn't work:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$validationBuilder = new Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuider();
```

The validator version is 2.3.2. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a \ at the beginning and you need the correct spelling of Buider

```
$validationBuilder = new \Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuilder();
```

Consider also using a use statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuilder;

$validationBuilder = new ValidatorBuilder();
```

==========================================

Make sure you are actually loading the autoload.php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

If you still have problems then please post the actual error message and your composer.json file.